# Optimized SQL Query user questions

Tags: sql-server

Users have multiple questions to answer and they are saved in tblAnswers.

**tblUsers**
**ID**  **Name**
1 Ray
2 Aaron
3 Kiran
**tblAnswers**
**ID** **UserID** **QuesID** **Answers**
1 1 1 mno
2 1  2 abc
3 1  3 xyz

I want the following query: Select UserName,Ques1 answer,Ques2 answer,Ques3 answer

I wast an optimized sql query for the above scenario. Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know you want all the results 1,2,3 in the same row but that is pretty complex and you can still read easily because with the ORDER BY the will be all together. Good luck!

```
SELECT UserName, CONCAT(tq.Question, ‘ ‘, ta.Answer) FROM tblUsers tu
INNER JOIN tblAnswers ta on tu.ID = ta.UserID
INNER JOIN tblQuestions tq on tq.ID = ta.QuesID
ORDER BY tu.UserID
```